# Can't Make a Composite Key? Where am i going wrong?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Im trying to make a many to many relationsship. A client needs to be able to have many administrations and an administration should be able to have many clients. My problem: In microsoft management studio the ClientId is somehow set to be the primary key, in the linking table. What am i doing wrong?

I have the following 3 models:

```
public class Client : IUser
{
    [Key, ForeignKey(nameof(User)), DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public User User { get; set; }
    public IList<ClientAdministration> ClientAdministrations { get; set;} 
}


public class Administration
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public IList<ClientAdministration> ClientAdministrations { get; set;}
}




public class ClientAdministration
{
    [key, Column(Order = 0)]
    public int ClientId { get; set; }
    public Client Client { get; set; }

    [key, Column(Order = 1)]
    public int AdministrationId { get; set; }
    public Administration Administration { get; set; }
}
```

In my Context.cs have defined the following relationsship:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<ClientAdministration>()
            .HasKey(ca => new { ca.ClientId, ca.AdministrationId });

        modelBuilder.Entity<ClientAdministration>()
            .HasOne<Client>(ca => ca.Client)
            .WithMany(c => c.ClientAdministrations)
            .HasForeignKey(ca => ca.ClientId);

        modelBuilder.Entity<ClientAdministration>()
            .HasOne<Administration>(ca => ca.Administration)
            .WithMany(a => a.ClientAdministrations)
            .HasForeignKey(ca => ca.AdministrationId);
```

Comment: Does the `ClientAdministration` table have any other columns? Or just the 2 key columns?

Comment: @jcruz No, just the two key columns :)

Comment: In that case you can omit the joining table all together from your C# code and use the fluent API configuration for this M2M mapping. See section "Configure a Many-to-Many Relationship using Fluent API" in the post: https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-many-to-many-relationship-in-code-first.aspx

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](https://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/configuration/data-annotation-attributes/key-attribute), the Key attribute defines the *primary key.*

In a linking table, both keys are foreign keys, not primary keys.